# rsyslog send specific lines to remote server

Tags: linux

I'm sending /var/log/messages with rsyslog to remote log server with this syntax

```
*.* @remote_server_ip:port
```

in /var/log/messages there lines as;

```
06-03-2021  11:26:50    System0.Info    10.0.0.124  Jun  3 11:26:50 neptun04 HDB_SYSTEMDB[2049]: 2021-06-03T11:26:50.093414Z;nameserver;server_name;EHP;00;30001;SYSTEMDB;server_ip;pordevdb;28522;62678;Session_Management;INFO;CONNECT;SYSTEM;;;;;;SYSTEM;SUCCESSFUL;;;;;;;;162347;unknown;;;;;SYSTEM;HANACockpit;SYSTEM;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

I want to send only those lines insted of all messages to remote rsyslog.

I've tried to add below line to /etc/rsyslog.conf to seperate lines starts with "HDB_SYSTEMD" to another log file (i thought if i can seperate i can send that log file only) but didn't work, it's not writing anything to hanna.log file;

```
*.*;mail.none;news.none                 -/var/log/messages
:msg, contains, "HDB_SYSTEMDB"          /var/log/hanna.log
```

How i can send specific lines to remote syslog server which contains "HDB_SYSTEMD"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it work and writing down the solution if anyone needed in future;

first editrsyslog.conf with  `nano /etc/rsyslog.conf` then add below lines;

```
#### save hana logs to another file ####
$template hanalog, "/var/log/hanalog"
if $programname contains 'HDB_SYSTEMD' then ?hanalog
& ~
```

after adding lines your config file should like this;
[config file preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPguZ.png)

then edit rsyslog.d file as `nano /etc/rsyslog.d/hana-log.conf` and add below template;

```
$ModLoad imfile    #Load the imfile input module

$InputFilePollInterval 10

$InputFileName  /var/log/hanalog

$InputFileTag hana-dberisim:

$InputFileStateFile stat-hana-dberisim

$InputFileSeverity Info

$InputRunFileMonitor


$template hana_dberisim, "  %msg% "


if $programname == 'hana-dberisim' then @remote_server_ip:port;hana_dberisim

if $programname == 'hana-dberisim' then stop
```

restart rsyslog service;

```
service rsyslog restart
```

Thats all.

Answer (score 0):

"HDB_SYSTEMDB" is not part of the message – it's the program name. (The whole field is the "syslog tag" – rsyslog automatically removes the [pid] suffix to determine the program name.) See [RSyslog message properties](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/properties.html).

```
:programname, isequal, "HDB_SYSTEMDB"
```

You can also match against the whole tag (with "name[pid]"):

```
:syslogtag, startswith, "HDB_SYSTEMDB"
```